# How can grant permission to execute a stored procedure on another database to specific master data services user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, master-data-services

Problem:

I need to grant permission to execute a stored procedure on another database to the master data services user that is handling the DML commands whenever I use the Master Data Services Excel add-in.

Context:

I added a SQL trigger to a master data services table. Whenever DML is used on the table the trigger need to execute a Stored Procedure on another database.

The user initiating the DML will be using the MDS Excel add-in.

However, an error is thrown in Excel whenever I click Publish (where data is pushed to the MDS db):

> The server principal
> "S-1-9-3-4000979447-1289397781-4196995230-646085745" is not able to
> access the database "IHS-Dataplatform" under the current security
> context., @ErrorNumber = 916, @ErrorProcedure =
> "dbo.ExecuteWhenTriggered", line 57

I can't find the server principal anywhere, hence I am not sure how I can give the access to execute on another database.

I tried to have the trigger execute a Stored Procedure on the MDS database itself. In order to do this, I needed to "GRANT EXECUTE ON" the Stored Procedure to the mds_schema_user. However, I can't grant execute on a stored procedure on another database as this user is a sql user without login.

Comment: If it's using a `USER` without a `LOGIN` what is being used to connect to the database? Is the database a contained database? If so then *no* references to another database should be in the database, that's the whole point of a contained database; everything is *contained* in that *one* database.

Comment: SQL Server Master Data Services is not a contained database. The add-in uses a webservice to communicate with the MDS 'engine' afaik. The windows user is used for authentication. But this is not the user that actually does the DML in the database.